# Netty 4.1 How to restart SSL session/handshake (hello request) from server side

Tags: java, ssl, https, netty

I'm newbie on Netty framework and i don't know how to send OpenSSL 'hello request' from server side.

**Netty SSlHandler:**

> Restarting the session
>
> To restart the SSL session, you must remove the existing closed
>   SslHandler from the ChannelPipeline, insert a new SslHandler with a
>   new SSLEngine into the pipeline, and start the handshake process as
>   described in the first section.

I have HTTPS server based on SnoopServer example, but when I'm trying to restart ssl nothing works as expected.

**e.g.**

```
// reset ssl session from server's HttpHandler 
SslContext sslCtx = null;
SelfSignedCertificate selfSignedCert;
try {
    selfSignedCert = new SelfSignedCertificate();
    sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(selfSignedCert.certificate(), selfSignedCert.privateKey()).sslProvider(SslProvider.JDK).build();
    } catch (CertificateException | SSLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

((SslHandler) ctx.pipeline().get("ssl")).close(ctx, ctx.newPromise());

if (ctx.pipeline().remove("ssl") != null && sslCtx != null) {
   ctx.pipeline().addFirst("sslNew", sslCtx.newHandler(ctx.channel().alloc()));
}
```

I need to restart the session because it is the unique way to restart handshake as explained in netty.io docs.

Then I need to ask: Are there any way to request the client hello from netty https snoop server?.

OpenSSL has the capability to send helloRequest from server to client and wait to the "Client Hello" but how?

Comment: The Netty authors are mistaken. 'Restart an SSL session' is meaningless. Whatever their implementation may require, at the JSSE and NIO level you can issue a new handshake over an existing SSL session using an existing `SSLEngine`.

Comment: mmm but Should I implement my own socketchannel with an httpsServer or TLSServer or socket directly ?. OpenSSL has the hello request capability, and netty implements OpenSSL, shouldn't netty be capable to issue the method?

Comment: All you should need to do is call `SSLEngine.beginHandshake()`, as far as I can see.

Comment: But you will have to tell us what you, or they, mean by 'restart an SSL session'. There is no such operation.

Comment: Yes what I want is to send a `Hello Request`from server side to issue a new handshake with the _client hello, server hello, ciphers exchange etc..._    
I don't know what is the proper  way to call directly the `beginHandshake()` method of the `sslEngine` maybe i should invalidate the session or restart it.           E.g. when the browser call localhost:8443/handshake, the HttpHandler receive the `HttpRequest` and issue the `restart handshake method`.

Comment: *Why?* What is the actual effect you desire? An abbreviated handshake? A full handshake? New keys within the same session? A new session? Upgrade the cipher suite? A client certificate?

Comment: I need to be able to request a new client hello each time I need because I'm using the extensions of it. Is that possible with netty NIO server?

Comment: What does 'using the extensions of it' mean? What is your *question*? There are several operations you can perform on an SSL session, but 'restarting' it is not one of them, as I first told you five days ago. Until you state your actual requirement it is impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: The Netty `SslHandler` has a `renegotiate` method, which _may_ do what you want - kick off a new handshake on the existing connection. How you call it from the Netty stack I'm not sure - perhaps `extend` the Netty `SslHander` to call `renegotiate` on some specific `userEventTriggered`?

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new handshake any time you like, and you certainly do *not* need a new `SSLEngine` for that.

However this either

- updates the current session, at a minimum by establishing a new session key, or possibly changing the cipher suite or acquiring a peer certificate, or
- creates a new session if you have invalidated the old session.

it does **not** 'restart' the session. There is no such operation.

Comment: Well I was trying to issue the new handshake, without restart session. I tried to `beginHandshake()` method by invalidating the session before and also without invalidate the session before and nothing make the client send a new client hello. I don't need to restart session actually I just need to receive a new client hello every time I need because the client adds information in the ssl extensions that I need to record.

Comment: Currently the only way to do this is a tcp reset